# Search for all data in GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork, http-post

I'd like to get a list of all metadata from GeoNetwork. According to this manual https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/developer/xml_services/metadata_xml_search_retrieve.html#search-metadata-xml-search I'm using this curl command

```
curl -X POST -u user:pass http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/xml.search
```

I want to do it using Python, so I'm using requests to send POST request to the same url as above. I am also sending this string as 'data' parameter of Python's POST request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request/>
```

The response comes with this element, among others:

```
<response from="1" to="100" selected="0" maxPageSize="100">
```

I'd like to get list of all metadata. The above request returns only 100 GeoNetwork records. How to get whole list, or another page of this list?

Is this link from above the official documentation for latest GeoNetwork version? I am using GN 3.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a **list** of all metadata in a GeoNetwork instance by looking at the sitemap.

The location of the sitemap in GeoNetwork has has changed over time but you can find it by looking at the robots.txt file.

GeoNetwork generates one at:

```
http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/robots.txt
```

GN 3.10.n has a site map at:

```
http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/api/sitemap
```

GN 2.10.n had a sitemap at:

```
http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/portal.sitemap
```

If you want to go the route of CSW then you can use a GetRecords POST request like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csw:GetRecords 
   xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2"
   xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd"
   service="CSW" 
   version="2.0.2"
   resultType="results"
   maxRecords="25"
   startPosition="26">
  <csw:Query typeNames="gmd:MD_Metadata">
    <csw:Constraint version="1.1.0">
      <Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"/>
    </csw:Constraint>
  </csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
```

with `Content-Type: application/xml` header

to http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw

To get records 26 to 51 and repeat...

If this file was called `getrecords-25to51.xml` then you could use a POST through cURL like:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --data-binary "@getrecords-25to51.xml" http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw
```

or even just

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --data-binary "@getrecords-25to51.xml" http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw
```

To get a list of just titles from a CSW service you can use a `GetDomain` request like:

```
http://geonetwork_server/geonetwork/srv/eng/csw?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetDomain&propertyname=title&
```

Comment: CSW worked, I should be able to adjust it to my needs. Somehow I couldn't use sitemap. There are GN errors (ServiceNotFoundEx when I try /sitemap) or I get something like only header of xml file (when I try /portal.sitemap). I might be doing something wrong, but it''s not that important now when CSW works.

Comment: good that csw works for you.  When I pull all records  from a GeoNetowork service I nearly always go the sitemap route, using python.  The sitemap location was different I think than the two listed in more recent versions, but the correct link should be discoverable in the robots.txt file.  What link does that suggest?

Comment: sitemap: http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/portal.sitemap and
sitemap: http://localhost:8080/geonetwork/srv/eng/portal.sitemap?format=rdf

Comment: All I managed to get from those was:   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:geo="http://www.google.com/geo/schemas/sitemap/1.0" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"/>
`

Comment: And this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><urlset xmlns:sc="http://sw.deri.org/2007/07/sitemapextension/scschema.xsd" xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"><sc:dataset><sc:datasetLabel>My GeoNetwork catalogue content catalogue for Linked Data spiders (RDF) </sc:datasetLabel><changefreq>daily</changefreq></sc:dataset></urlset>`   when used with parameter format=rdf

Comment: Odd, well the location is correct, and the correct schema, but an empty set of data.  Seems like a misconfiguration issue somewhere in the GeoNetwork settings; possibly worthy of another question